# Destination server files moved and Rsync copying same fiels again

Tags: bash, rsync

I am using `rsync` for a longtime and it works perfectly as required, but I came across a situation where the destination server files are moved every few seconds and `rsync` copying the same files again from local sftp server.  I was using `--ignore-existing` command but it does not work too in this situation.

```
sshpass -p "ABCDE" rsync   -avvtzh   --ignore-existing -e  "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"  --log-file="/home/toor/log/uc.log"   admin@71.122.227.193:share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Lanein1/Unicard/ /home/toor/UCDownloads/
```

Comment: Make the destination server do hardlinks instead of moves, use the log filed to exclude (an increasingly large list) or delete source files after the transfer.

Answer (score 0):

If the destination files have been moved, then as far as `rsync` is concerned they no longer exist. The `--ignore-existing` flag is of no use because the files do not exist where they are expected to be, so there's nothing to ignore.

You could create a flag file and only push files modified since the last successful `rsync` run. Something like this skelton could work (it's more complicated that you might expect because the source of the files is on your remote system rather than local):

```
path='/share/CACHEDEV1_DATA/Lanein1/Unicard'
flag="$path.flag"

# Must have a flag file. If we don't then create one from the epoch
if ssh -nq admin@71.122.227.193 "[ ! -f '$flag' ]"
then
    touch -t 197001010000 /tmp/1970
    scp -p /tmp/1970.flag admin@71.122.227.193:"$flag"
    rm -f /tmp/1970.flag
fi

# Flag the start of the synchronisation
ssh -nq admin@71.122.227.193 "date >'$flag.tmp'"

# Copy files newer than the flag
if ssh -nq admin@71.122.227.193 "find '$path/' -depth -newer '$flag' -print0 |
    rsync -avz --files-from - --from0 admin@71.122.227.193:/ /home/toor/UCDownloads/
then
    # Install the new flag
    ssh -nq admin@71.122.227.193 "mv -f '$flag.tmp' '$flag'"
fi
```

For those people not familiar with a QNAP, the `touch` command doesn't exist as standard, and `rsync` is cut down in its functionality. I've used `touch` on the local client to create a file dated 1970-01-01 and then I transfer that to the remote system as the initial flag. (If `touch` existed on the remote system it would have been far easier to create the file remotely in the first place.) The `find` includes only files and directories created/modified since the date of the flag.